# JavaScript typeof Operator-Number vs String

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, typeof

In the example typeof (3 + 4); returns number.
Then the example typeof (3 + 4) + 1; returns number1.

So instead of adding it to 7, it treats the + 1 as a string but says it's a number?

I find this confusing. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: it's like `( typeof (3 + 4) ) + 1` which is `number + 1` which is `number1`

Comment: read as `(typeof (3 + 4)) + 1`.

Comment: And this, typeof 1 + (3 + 4); returns number7.

Comment: Not sure why I would get voted down for asking a question -1 ... that's just rude.

Comment: @LucyK- I am also surprised.+1 for good question .Please accept the answer that best fit for your question.It will help for people in future.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case `+` acting as a string concatenation. So  `typeof (3 + 4)` gives number & `+` contact number & 1 that is why it is number1

Comment: And apparently parentheses takes precedence over the typeof operand so in the case of, typeof 1 + (3 + 4); 3 and 4 get added first so it doesn't get treated as a string yet, then typeof returns the string, number ... yes, it can get confusing ... thanks for helping me clear this up!

Answer (score 1):

`typeof (3 + 4);` returns `"number"`, a String, adding a Number to a String will just append the number to it, meaning

`typeof (3 + 4) + 1;` is essentially `"number" + 1` which is `"number1"`

And, yeah, `typeof 1 + (3 + 4);` will add the sum of 3 and 4 to `typeof 1` and then return `"number7"`

Comment: Ah ok, and so the operand is a string and JavaScript will convert a number to a string ... got it ... I wondered about that ... thank you

Comment: Yes. `typeof` will return a String which will force JS to add the number to it as a String

Answer (score 1):

> The **`typeof`** operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> > **The `typeof` operator is followed by its operand:**
> >
> > ***`typeof` UnaryExpression***
>
> **Parameters**
>
> > ***`operand` is an expression representing the object or primitive whose type is to be returned.***
> >
> > ***The parentheses are optional.***

In 1st Case[**typeof (3 + 4)]**: **3+4=7** and this is a **number type** so it giving output as **Number**

In 2nd Case[**typeof (3 + 4)+1]**: **3+4=7** and this is a **number type** so **Number+1**(just string concatenation) is giving output as **Number1**

```js
console.log(typeof (3 + 4));
console.log(typeof (3 + 4)+1);
```